# How to write an SQL query to get information out of multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that will satisfy the following conditions:

Given a list of uids (6,8,10), get name_first and name_last of the users that have the permission 'Administer users'.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
uid INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
status TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
name_first VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT '',
name_last VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT '',
email VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);

CREATE TABLE role(
rid INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(256),
PRIMARY KEY `rid` (`rid`)
);

CREATE TABLE users_roles (
uid INT(11),
rid INT(11),
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
KEY `rid` (`rid`)
);

CREATE TABLE permissions (
rid INT(11),
permission VARCHAR(64),
UNIQUE KEY (`rid`, `permission`)
);

INSERT INTO users (uid, status, name_first, name_last, email) 
VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Joe', 'Montana', ''),
(2, 1, 'Eli', 'Manning', ''), 
(3, 1, 'Peyton', 'Manning', ''), 
(4, 1, 'Steve', 'Young', ''), 
(5, 1, 'John', 'Elway', ''), 
(6, 1, 'Robert', 'Griffin', ''), 
(7, 1, 'Joe', 'Montana', ''),
(8, 1, 'Tom', 'Brady', ''),
(9, 1, 'Drew', 'Brees', ''),
(10, 1, 'Andrew', 'Luck', '');

INSERT INTO role (rid, name) 
VALUES
(1, 'Teacher'),
(2, 'Athletic Directory'),
(3, 'Administrator');

INSERT INTO permissions (rid, permission) VALUES
(1, 'Administer users'),
(1, 'Administer courses'),
(1, 'Build Unicorns'),
(2, 'Administer groups'),
(3, 'Administer users'),
(3, 'Administer school');

INSERT INTO users_roles (uid, rid) VALUES
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(3, 3),
(4, 1),
(5, 1),
(6, 2),
(7, 2),
(8, 3),
(10, 1);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT name_first, name_last FROM users
JOIN users_roles
ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
JOIN role
ON role.rid = users_roles.rid
JOIN permissions
ON users.uid = permissions.rid
WHERE users.uid = 8 AND permissions.permission = 'Administer users';
```

This is my first attempt at writing SQL and I've confused myself trying to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check you join condition `users.uid = permissions.rid`, what do you expect this is going to do?

Comment: No I cant, upon looking at it further, the permissions table does not have uid as a foreign key.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? *SQL* is a standard - yet vendors often implement it differently, so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of `auto_increment` and the dreaded backticks

Answer (score 0):

```
ON users.uid = permissions.rid
```

Should be

```
ON role.rid = permissions.rid
```

Because not all of your records relate to other tables if you want to see NULL values you need to use LEFT JOIN (an OUTER JOIN) rather than INNER JOIN.

Further you should move the permission = 'admin...' to an on condition if you want to see all of the records or it is just the same as an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN users_roles ur
    ON u.uid = ur.uid
    LEFT JOIN role r
    ON ur.rid = r.rid
    LEFT JOIN permissions p
    ON r.rid = p.rid
    AND p.permission = 'Administer users'
WHERE
    u.uid IN (6,8,10);
```

Comment: That works for when I have users.uid = 8, but how can I check for uids 6 and 10 as well? I wrote out separate WHERE statements and got an error.

Comment: Use LEFT JOINS instead of INNER JOINS because not all of your users are assigned to a role and permission

Comment: I tried what u posted above and it didnt work, it gave me all the first and last names rather than just the ones for uids 6, 8 and 10.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6955/314

Comment: @TimoorKurdi sorry I usually write for sql-server not mysql and I added the WHERE statement after the fact so the ";" semi colon I had after the AND p.permission - 'adminis...' caused you to get all of the users.  here is a sqlfiddle with syntax modified.  I added all of the columns ("*") so you can see the results from all tables instead of only first and last name in your question lists. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6955/325/0

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra column just in case you need it.  I created temp tables for testing so just remove the hash tags from the query:

```
SELECT
     U.name_first
    ,U.name_last
    ,P.permission PermissionName
    ,R.name RoleName
FROM
    #users U
    JOIN #users_roles UR
        ON  U.uid= UR.uid
    LEFT JOIN #role R
        ON  UR.rid = R.rid
    LEFT JOIN #permissions P
        ON  UR.rid = P.rid
WHERE
    U.uid IN (6,8,10)
    AND P.permission = 'Administer users'
;
```

Comment: because you have a condition in your where clause that limites the results by a table you have a LEFT JOIN on you are essentially doing an inner join.  You need to move p.permission = 'admin...' to the ON condition section of the join

Comment: @Matt You are correct that use of the WHERE clause referencing a left join is an inner join. However, I do this based on MY assumption I want to see how the tables interact when I am not using the WHERE clause. The role and permissions tables are independent of each other, so I use two left joins.  If you do not have that need or there is no benefit in your case you can use joins. However, in either case you do not have to move the condition from the WHERE clause to the ON condition. It is based on which is potentially easier for a third party to read and which is more dynamic. Good Luck!

Comment: @Matt I am not disagreeing with you. I can only tell what has worked for me in the past. Often end-users requirements change, so I try to balance the efficiency of the code with code that can be quickly and easily changed based on the fickle needs of end-users.  However, if I wanted to me more concise in my code I probably still would not move the the permissions from the WHERE clause to the ON clause, but it may just be a difference of style.

Comment: `SELECT
     U.name_first
    ,U.name_last
    ,P.permission PermissionName
FROM
    #users U
    JOIN #users_roles UR
        ON  U.uid= UR.uid
    JOIN #permissions P
        ON  UR.rid = P.rid
WHERE
    U.uid IN (6,8,10)
    AND P.permission = 'Administer users'
;`

Answer (score 0):

try this but u will not get uid (6) because it not has permission of "Administer users".

select name_first, name_last from users where uid in
(select uid from users_roles where rid in
(select rid from permissions where permission ='Administer users')) and uid in (6,8,10);

Comment: if you need 6 too then UPDATE `users_roles` SET `rid` = '1' WHERE `users_roles`.`uid` = 6;